# Java combining two hashmaps of the same type into a new hashmap keeping duplicates

Tags: java, java-stream

Assume we are given:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("111","Frank");
map1.put("222","Ted");
map1.put("555","Peter");

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("333","Roger");
map2.put("222","Ted");
map2.put("888","Kent");
map2.put("555","Peter");
```

How could I go about combining both of these into a new map:

```
Map<String, String> combinedMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I wanted to do it in a java stream way, so my attempt was:

```
combinedMap = Stream.of(map1, map2)
                        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

But I was hit with some duplicate key error. I believe I could also just do a `combinedMap.putAll(map1)` and `combinedMap.putAll(map2)` but I'm not sure if that's the best way possible.

Comment: You are correct, `map1.putAll(map2)` or the `combinedMap` you detail above is probably the best method. When you say "keeping duplicates", the map will overwrite elements with the same key.

Comment: Worry about finding **a** way that gets the job done, rather than **the best** way.  You can waste a lot of time _trying_ to find the "best" way to solve one problem that could be better spent _actually  solving_ all the other problems you need to solve...

Comment: This solution will throw an illegal state exception for duplicate keys, you should provide a merge function: a, b -> b if you want to keep the latest value for a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it with your use of a Java stream.  The only thing you missed that you can provide a "merger function" that takes care of resolving collisions when the same key exists in both maps.  Since it doesn't matter in our case which one we pick, I added a very simple merger that just pick one of them arbitrarily:

```
combinedMap = Stream.of(map1, map2)
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1));

System.out.println(combinedMap);
```

Results:

```
{111=Frank, 222=Ted, 333=Roger, 555=Peter, 888=Kent}
```

Comment: This is more in line of what my code needed, thank you very much I understand it!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep duplicates, then Map is not the correct data-structure. You need something like a [MultiMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html) or `Map<String,List<String>>`.

An Example:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(combine(Map.of("111", "sam"), Map.of("222", "joe", "111","tim")));
    }

    public static Map<String, List<String>> combine(Map<String, String>... maps) {
        return Arrays.stream(maps).flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> Arrays.asList(e.getValue()), (v1, v2) -> Stream.of(v1, v2).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your final HashMap can have multiple entries for a single key, then you must store these entries in some sort of a sequence. There is simply no other way around it.

As suggested by other users, the previous entry with the same key will be replaced with the new entry if the entry is not a sequence.